# Intermittent computer Shutdowns/Reboots. IS PSU malfunctioning?

Tags: power-supply

My desktop is rebooting intermittently. I did look through Windows logs but they were not very helpful. One log shows as failed to create an error dump file!

Here is my computer info:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
Other OS Description Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-LGQFFEI
System Manufacturer ASUS
System Model System Product Name
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU SKU
Processor AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor, 4001 Mhz, 16 Core(s), 32 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 2423, 8/9/2021
SMBIOS Version 3.3
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product PRIME B550M-A (WI-FI)
BaseBoard Version Rev X.0x
Platform Role Desktop
Secure Boot State Off
PCR7 Configuration Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory C:\WINDOWS
System Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "10.0.22621.1413"

I watched many YouTube troubleshooting videos, One pointed me to PSU testing.

I ran a stress test using HWiNFO64 and watched the voltage using HWMonitor(motherboard)
. As soon as I start the stress test  3.3V starts dropping to values as low as 3v(and even lower to 2.95v) See below:
```

[image]

Does the above mean it is time to replace my PSU?

Thanks to cyBernard comment , I looked at ATX Specs:

Generally, supply voltages must be within ±5% of their nominal values at all times. The little-used negative supply voltages, however, have a ±10% tolerance. There is a specification for ripple in a 10 Hz–20 MHz bandwidth:[3]

```
Supply (V)  Tolerance   Range, min. to max. (V) Ripple, p. to p., max. (mV)
+5  ±5% (±0.25 V)   +4.75 V to +5.25    50
−5  ±10% (±0.50 V)  −4.50 V to −5.50    50
+12 ±5% (±0.60 V)   +11.40 V to +12.60  120
−12 ±10% (±1.20 V)  −10.80 V to −13.20  120
+3.3    ±5% (±0.165 V)  +3.135 V to +3.465  50
+5 standby  ±5% (±0.25 V)   +4.75 V to +5.25    50
```

So for $ 3.3-volt, the minimum voltage is 3.135 but my PSU drops even under 3V.

Comment: Always the best approach to this question is to get the Manufacturer's Hardware Test App and test all the hardware, particularly Motherboard.

Comment: Reasonable DC voltages does not prove if the PS is good or bad. It could be there is AC ripple or RFI on the lines; could be there's an intermittent that only shows up on occasion. That said, there are *many* possible causes besides PS for that issue. Is there anything in the *Error Log* (not a full core dump)?

Comment: There is an error log saying creation of dump file failed. This  further makes be suspicious this could be a power problem.

Comment: if this was a software/driver issue system had time to log aome error but it seems otherwise.

Comment: Agian I must say issue only shows when computer Cpu gpu are on heavy loads.

Comment: The other possibility is faulty RAM. Especially the symptom is that the computer just suddenly reboots, without any noise from power supply.

Comment: @ckhan Interesting to know.  At least in my experience faulty  RAM only caused a blue screen not causing reboot.

Comment: According to the ATX specs your PSU 12v should be with 5% of 12v or 11.4v.  The fact that you have a 11.3v means your power supply isn't big enough.  Your 12v should not be lower than 11.9 on a regular basis.

Comment: @cyberMed I ordered a new PSU. I will update this post if issue goes away.

Comment: Running mdsched(memory test tool) did not report any issues.

Comment: finally caught the culprit. It was the  PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced my old PSU with ASUS ROG Strix 850W PSU.

Now all voltages are pretty stable. Especially 3.3V stays at V3.296 and never hits 3.2V.

I ran 2 heavy VR games for a couple of hours and no crashes/Reboots anymore.

Thanks for all of the comments and feedback!